# What would be the logical requirements on a language, in order to do direct meta-programming in it?

Tags: proof-techniques, software-verification, code-generation, reversible-computing, meta-programming

I am motivated by the idea of generating “words” or “pairs” in a programming language or set of commands.

For example, consider any arbitrary REST API.

Beyond requesting the original URL endpoint, assume the structure of the API commands are keys and values (a dictionary of parameters).

Some of the parameters may be required, and some may be optional, and some are not valid (ie, making up random parameter names that aren’t supported). Some of the values for each key may be valid (return no error), syntactically correct but invalid (returns an error), or syntactically incorrect (unparseable, a type error, passing a string to an Int).

Also, these properties - of accepted or rejected on the parse level, and of executed without error or with - can have conditionality relations on the values of other keys and values present.

Perhaps we can consider a set of words, a graph of dependency links, and a terminal node, “correct” and “incorrect”.

(We abstract away the difference between a parameter and a value, making the presence of some value a condition for a parameter to evaluate as correct, perhaps.)

If we consider “types” as arbitrary, because they are data formats which a programming language has conditional instructions on what to do, upon parsing the format and creating a symbolic representation for its “type”, we can say that in computer memory (binary), assume with have *a* arbitrary *types*.

If the set of commands (of the API) does not somehow have a programmatically-parsible description of the requirements of its commands (the above stated deterministic graph which tells you the outcome for any given input), maybe you could figure it out yourself through trial and error. It may w feel like a messier way to do things, but the point is that the information is available, one way or another, (I think).

So, we are considering an algorithm that can tell you if an input is correct or not without executing the actual API (hypothetically, imagine it is like minesweeper and we don’t want to let ourselves make a single wrong call during the real deal).

We also want to generate all valid expressions (of input for the API) of length *n*. Why? Well, maybe we think it’s useful to see a lot of little small pre-formulated expressions we can use, and generate a complete set, automatically.

So… I think we are considering the difference between a proof-checker vs. a full-on complete set of expressions, in a formal language? Something to do with correctness (- consistency with the program’s syntactic allowances, or rules), and completeness.

I have been thinking a ton about induction, formal languages, and combinatorial enumeration, so that’s informing the question, in part.

The “program” which can check if an input expression is “correct” already needs an internal representation or knowledge of very much about the program itself - what character encodings (UTF-8, hex, etc.) does it use, what data types are there, what is the actual logic of the API’s back-end, so we can try to check if an input makes sense logically?

First of all, it makes me wonder if there’s a proof in theoretical computer science that any program which can check the correctness of an input to a different program, would necessarily have the identical total knowledge of the actual program itself? Sounds like the Halting problem.

Second of all, if there is not a deep logical difference, in terms of information content, between a program $P$, and a program $C_P(i) = {0, 1}$, which checks the output of input $i$ with regard to $P$, assigning it one of two values in this case (error / no error, but it could be anything, true or false, terminates / does not terminate), does it follow that any program which implicitly ‘knows’ everything about $P$ is some kind of… ‘reconfiguration’ of $P$, like an isomorphic structure, for example?

What I am getting at, is there may be an “inversion” of a program, $P^{-1}$, which generates all of the valid expressions according to $P$. Assuming that P is some sort of “transformation grammar” (?) of the sort<sup>*</sup>:

```
if input character c == ‘0’:
  check if next char c+1 == ‘1’
  if yes:
    substitute ‘c c+1’ with ‘D’
…
```

The above program means to show that the program has to “bootstrap” from nothing but an incoming binary stream / sequence using (what I assume to be the essentials of a Turing machine) conditionals, infinite loops, and the ability to write symbols somewhere (in memory) and return them, based on the input symbols it reads in (and in the idealized case, assume error-handling occurs much higher up in a programming language, so the idealized machine never receives binary input it is not specified what to do with - there would be no errors down on this level.)

---

<sup>*</sup>(where `D` is some tag for a data type, for example, the prefix to a function body, or integer sequence, or something).

---

Program $P$ has a precise set of rules for parsing arbitrary binary input into let us say strong, explicit symbolic representations or tags for the data types which will be used in the program - I guess, significantly decreasing the amount of “context” it will need thereafter, because it can from then on (I guess it’s called a “lexer”?) determine the expression type of any incoming expression through a much simpler, single-layer conditional statement (in principle, anyway), like:

```
If input sequence b begins with:
  “0000”:
    b is type NULL
  “0001”:
    b is type INT
  “0011”:
    b is type STRING
  “1010”:
    b is type ABCKDKD
```

---

*(where ABCKDKD is any arbitrary type, since a type is an algorithmically defined construct)*

---

*If* the program can parse input string into higher level symbolic representations (beyond just data types, everything in the computer is symbol re-writing (where the “symbols” have binary representations/encodings/translations/forms), perhaps if reformulated mathematically, as functions between sets, or using category theory; does a theorem guarantee, refute, or provide a condition, on the reversibility of a program?

If a parser is reversible, to me it would imply, just as I can enter UTF-8 symbols (as binary) into an API call, and the program “parses” (and executes) on that incoming data, rewriting it into final form (which it outputs), somehow I could turn the program inside out, and have it deterministically provide me with all the input expressions it recognizes as valid, somehow. But I’m not sure if this is confirmed, refuted, or a topic with further conditions on it.

If a parser of a language is equivalent to a generator for that language (like, programs that can both parse a language, like a controlled version of English, as well as generate arbitrary (controlled) English sentences), I suppose that implies some conditions on the properties of the language itself?

Because I believe most programming languages, including Python, can’t be completely proof-checked, but there are frameworks like Agda, which aim to prove a lack of any possible faulty conditions or states in all possible execution paths of a program. Right?

We could extend this to “proofs” about systems in general, not just computer programs. For any given system described in certain kinds of rules (rules of this or that form or type), we can assess if it is “provable” or not. It may be desirable to try to design it as a provable system, and then prove it. (I am motivated by stuff like state diagrams and Xstate.js where you can try to observe possible malfunctions in any system, like a factory, social system, public administration service, bureaucracy, organization, operation, etc.)

Comment: Some interesting related stuff anyway: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/computer+science https://github.com/andrejbauer/alg